# How to cast $ and , in an input text field as a variable in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, casting, textfield

I basically have a function that accepts input from a text field. Allowed characters in the text field include commas and dollar signs. So, my question is, how can I cast the input value as a Number, if there is a dollar sign or comma included? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Flex you can use CurrencyFormatter:

```
<s:CurrencyFormatter id="currencyFormatter" 
    currencySymbol="$"                           
    decimalSeparator="," 
    groupingSeparator="."
    useCurrencySymbol="true"/>

// in your function:
var number:Number = currencyFormatter.parse(text).value;
```

If you are not using Flex or if you need more flexibility, you can use parseFloat with a regex to remove the dollar sign and replace commas for dots:

```
text = text.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
var number:Number = parseFloat(text);
```